# What's the maximal ordinal day of the month to be mentioned in the Torah?

Tags: tanach

Out of the 30  days of the month, what's the maximal ordinal day of the month to be mentioned in the Torah? (especially in the first five books)

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/113709/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first five books:

בראשית פרק ח
פסוק יד

וּבַחֹדֶשׁ הַשֵּׁנִי בְּשִׁבְעָה וְעֶשְׂרִים יוֹם לַחֹדֶשׁ יָבְשָׁה הָאָרֶץ

Comment: A quick Sefaria search on 28, 29, and 30 confirms that this is the highest in all of Tanach (since months have at most 30 days).

Comment: Also Kings 2:25:27

Comment: @Doniel Samuel 1:20:5 is the 29th of the month

Comment: @Double Yes, but it doesn’t actually say “29th” in the passuk - just מחר חדש.