# All explicit dates in Tanakh

Tags: tanach, calendar

What are all the dates mentioned in Tanakh?

This question seeks all dates that are explicitly mentioned in the verses. No chronological extrapolation or exposition allowed here.

The date could be the date of a historical event, a religious injunction, or a prophecy. We may or may not have all the parts of the date available. Please list the verse, date, and if you can a one sentence summary of its significance.

There will be one wiki answer for dates by book, and when that is done we can rearrange the information into a second wiki answer in calendrical order.

This could be a useful resource for people looking for historical significance of various dates.

(If such a collection already exists please post it as an answer, but the amount of data involved should be manageable enough for us to maintain explicitly here as well. Please help out!)

Comment: How isn’t this too broad?

Comment: @Doniel How is it? There's already an answer with ~1/3 the work done and it's well within the character limit (if that's the relevant metric)

Comment: How difficult would one of these be with chazalic data

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Every date mentioned in any midrash? Sounds much more difficult to find them all at least.

Comment: @DoubleAA perhaps it can be limited to the Talmuds and Seder Olam (Midrash Rabbah..), well yes, a much more exhaustive project

Comment: Are we also looking for dates like "3rd year of Yehoyakim's reign" in Daniel 1:1 that don't have a month or day of the month?

Comment: @magicker I had been thinking of dates that have at least a day or month, so they could be plotted somewhat on a calendar. Year only events are numerous in relation to kings and generally of interest for long term chronology. If you have a different opinion please do say so and why

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Genesis

7:11 – 17 [Iyyar/Marcheshvan](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=text) (600th year of Noach's life); the Flood begins
8:4 – 17 [Tishrei/Nissan](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=text) (); the Ark lands in the Ararat mountains
8:5 – 1 [Tevet/Tammuz](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=text) (); water recedes sufficiently for the mountaintops to be visible
8:13 – 1 [Nissan/Tishrei](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=text) (601st year of Noach's life); the floodwaters abate and Noach opens the top of the Ark
8:14 – 27 [Iyyar/Marcheshvan](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=9&daf=11b&format=text) (); the land has dried after the Flood

#### Exodus

16:1 – 15 Iyyar (1st year out of Egypt); the Jews arrive at the Desert of Sin
19:1 – ?? Sivan (1st year out of Egypt); the Jews arrive at the Sinai Desert
40:17 – 1 Nissan (2nd year); the Mishkan is set up

#### Leviticus

#### Numbers

1:1 – 1 Iyyar (2nd year out of Egypt); command to count the Jews
9:1 – 1 Nissan (2nd year out of Egypt); command to offer the Korban Pesach in the desert
10:11 – 20 Iyyar (2nd year out of Egypt); the cloud rose from the camp initiating travel from Mt Sinai
20:1 – ?? Nissan (); Jewish nation arrives in Midbar Tzin and Miriam dies
33:3 – 15 Nissan (1st year of Exodus); Jews leave Egypt
33:38 – 1 Av (40th year out of Egypt); Aharon dies on Hor Hahar

#### Deuteronomy

1:3 – 1 Shevat (40th year in desert); Moshe gives farewell speech to nation

#### Joshua

4:19 – 10 Nissan (); Jews crossed the Jordan river into Israel
5:10 – 14 Nissan (); Jews offer Korban Pesach in Gilgal

#### Judges

*No dates*

#### Samuel

*No dates*

#### Kings

1:6:1 – ?? Iyyar (480th year from the Exodus, 4th year of Shlomo’s reign); beginning of the building of the Temple
1:6:38 – ?? Marheshvan (11th year of Shlomo’s reign); the Temple was completed
1:8:2 –  ?? Tishrei (); the people gather for the dedication of the Temple
1:12:32-33 – 15 Marheshvan (); Yerovam institutes his own festival and offers sacrifices in Bethel
2:25:1 – 10 Tevet (9th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Nebuchadnezzar besieges Jerusalem
2:25:2-4 – 9 ?? (11th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Jerusalem’s defenses are breached after a long famine
2:25:8-9 – 7 Av (19th year of Nebuchadnezzar’s reign); Nebuzaraddan comes to Jerusalem and burns down the Temple, the Royal Palace and all of Jerusalem’s houses
2:25:25 – ?? Tishrei (); Gedaliah is assassinated
2:25:27 – 27 Adar (37th year since Yehoyakhin's exile); Yehoyakhin is released from prison

#### Isaiah

*No dates*

#### Jeremiah

1:3 – ?? Av (11th year of Zedekiah’s reign); exile of Jerusalem
28:1 – ?? Av (4th year of Zedekiah’s reign); optimistic, false prophecy of Hananiah son of Azur
28:17 – ?? Tishrei (4th year of Zedekiah’s reign); death of Hananiah
36:9 – ?? Kislev (5th year of Yehoyakim’s reign); they declared a fast in Jerusalem
36:22 – ?? Kislev (); the king burned Jeremiah’s scroll
39:1 – ?? Tevet (9th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Nebuchadrezzar besieges Jerusalem
39:2 – 9 Tammuz (11th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Jerusalem’s defenses are breached
41:1-2 – ?? Tishrei (); Gedaliah is assassinated
52:4 – 10 Tevet (9th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Nebuchadrezzar besieges Jerusalem
52:5-6 – 9 Tammuz (11th year of Zedekiah’s reign); Jerusalem’s defenses are breached after a prolonged famine
52:12-13 – 10 Av (19th year of Nebuchadrezzar’s reign); Nebuzaraddan comes to Jerusalem and burns down the Temple, the Royal Palace and all of Jerusalem’s houses
52:31 – 25 Adar (37th year since Yehoyakhin's exile); Yehoyakhin is released from prison

#### Ezekiel

1:1-2 – 5 Tammuz (5th year since Yehoyakhin's exile); vision of "the chariot"
8:1 – 5 Elul (6th year); vision of trip to Jerusalem to see sinners in Temple
20:1 – 10 Av (7th year); people come to Ezekiel and his historical summary response
24:1 – 10 Tevet (9th year); announcement of the siege of Jerusalem
26:1 – 1 ?? (11th year); vision of downfall of Tyre
29:1 – 12 Tevet (10th year); vision of downfall of Egypt
29:17 – 1 Nissan (27th year); vision of success of Nebuchadnezzar
30:20 – 7 Nissan (11th year); vision of fall of Pharaoh
31:1 – 1 Sivan (11th year); vision of Egypt vs. Assyria
32:1 – 1 Adar (12th year); lament of Pharaoh's fall to the Babylonians
32:17 – 15 ?? (12th year); predicting the death of Egypt
33:21 – 5 Tevet (12th year); Ezekiel receives word of the fall of Jerusalem
40:1 – 10 Tishrei (14th year since fall of Jerusalem); vision of the setup of the third Temple
45:18 – 1 Nissan (); special prophetic Temple offerings
45:20 – 7 Nissan (); special prophetic Temple offerings

#### The Twelve

**Hosea**
*No dates*
**Joel**
*No dates*
**Amos**
*No dates*
**Obadiah**
*No dates*
**Jonah**
*No dates*
**Micah**
*No dates*
**Havakuk**
*No dates*
**Zephania**
*No dates*
**Nachum**
*No dates*
**Haggai**
1:1 – 1 Elul (2nd year of Darius); prophecy about building the second Temple
1:15 – 24 Elul (2nd year of Darius); building the second Temple
2:1 – 21 Tishrei (2nd year of Darius); prophecy about the grandeur of the second Temple
2:10 – 24 Kislev (2nd year of Darius); prophecy about testing the priest's knowledge of halakha
**Zecharia**
1:1 – ?? Marcheshvan (2nd year of Darius); exhortation to repent
1:7 – 24 Shevat (2nd year of Darius); vision of horseman
7:1 – 4 Kislev (4th year of Darius); answer should the Jews fast in Av
**Malachi**
*No dates*

#### Psalms

*No dates*

#### Proverbs

*No dates*

#### Job

*No dates*

#### Song of Songs

*No dates*

#### Ruth

*No dates*

#### Lamentations

*No dates*

#### Ecclesiastes

*No dates*

#### Esther

2:16 – ?? Tevet (7th year of Ahaseureus); Esther is taken to Ahaseureus' palace
3:7  – ?? Nissan (12th year of Ahaseureus); Haman throws lots to pick a date to kill the Jews
3:12 – 13 Nissan (); The order to kill the Jews is written
8:9  – 23 Sivan (); The order to allow the Jews to defend themselves is written
9:1  – 13 Adar (); The Jews defeat many of their enemies
9:17-18 – 14 Adar (); Most Jews rest and celebrate while the Jews in Shushan fight again
9:18 – 15 Adar (); The Jews in Shushan rest and celebrate

#### Daniel

#### Ezra

3:1 – ?? Tishrei (); the Jews who were in their cities gathered together in Jerusalem and rebuilt the altar
3:6 – 1 Tishrei (); they begin sacrificing on the altar, in the absence of a rebuilt temple
3:8 – ?? Iyyar (2nd year after their arrival in Jerusalem); the Levites were tasked with overseeing the rebuilding of the temple
6:15 – 3 Adar (6th year of Darius); the Second Temple is completed
6:19 – 14 Nissan (); performance of the Pesach service by the returnees
7:8-9 – 1 Av (7th year of Artaxerxes); Ezra and company arrive in Jerusalem
7:9 – 1 Nissan (); Ezra and company leave Babylon
8:31 – 12 Nissan (); Ezra and company left the River Ahava towards Jerusalem
10:9 – 20 Kislev (); Ezra gathers the nation to reprimand them
10:16 – 1 Tevet (); Jews begin sending away gentile wives
10:17 – 1 Nissan (); they finished sending away gentile wives
11:1 – ?? Kislev (20th year of Artaxerxes); Nehemiah is informed of the difficulties facing the inhabitants of Judea and Jerusalem
12:1 – ?? Nisan (20th year of Artaxerxes); Nehemiah requests to be sent to Jerusalem
16:15 – 25 Elul (); completion of the rebuilding of the walls of Jerusalem
17:72-18:1 – ?? Tishrei (); the Jews who were in their cities gathered together and requested that Ezra read the Torah to them
18:2 – 1 Tishrei (); Ezra read the Torah to the people
19:1 – 24 Tishrei (); they had a public fast day

#### Chronicles

1:12:16 – ?? Nissan (); men crossed the Jordan to join David
2:3:2 – ?? Iyyar (4th year of Shlomo’s reign); beginning of the building of the Temple
2:5:3 – ?? Tishrei (); the people gather for the dedication of the Temple
2:7:10 – 23 Tishrei (); Shlomo sends the people home
2:15:10 – ?? Sivan (15th year of Asa’s reign); the people gathered in Jerusalem and forged a covenant with G-d
2:29:3 – ?? Nissan (1st year of Hezekiah’s reign); Hezekiah opened the Temple doors and strengthened them
2:29:17 –  1 Nissan (); the priests began to sanctify the Temple
2:29:17 –  8 Nissan (); the priests came to the Sanctuary
2:29:17 –  16 Nissan (); the priests finished the sanctification
2:30:13 – ?? Iyyar (); a large number of people gather in Jerusalem for the Festival of Matzot
2:30:15 – 14 Iyyar (); slaughter of the Pesach during the reign of Hezekiah
2:31:7 – ?? Sivan (); they began piling up tithes
2:31:7 – ?? Tishrei (); they finished giving the tithes
2:35:1 and 19 – 14 Nissan (18th year of Josiah); slaughter of the Pesach

Comment: If you're reasonably sure there are no other dates in a book, remove the ellipsis from the end of its list.

Comment: Do you want to exclude repeating events?  Because you didn't include the musafim but you also didn't put a ...

Comment: @Heshy I think i found listing the all holidays in all the different places they are listed boring, honestly. Maybe we really should include them.

Comment: @DoubleAA One could be mechalek between a recorded historical event, prophecy, instruction that happened on a certain date in history, versus a date on which there is a commandment to perform certain observances

Comment: @DoubleAA Although that may also rule out your items from Yechezkel 45

Answer (score 2):

Here are the references in the other answer arranged in calendrical order.

1 Nissan: [Genesis 8:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.13?lang=bi&aliyot=0), [Exodus 40:17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.40.17?lang=bi&aliyot=0), [Numbers 9:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.9.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0), [Ezekiel 29:17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.29.17?lang=bi), [45:18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.45.18?lang=bi), Ezra 7:9, 10:17, Chronicles 2:29:17
7 Nissan: [Ezekiel 30:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.30.20?lang=bi), [45:20](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.45.20?lang=bi)
8 Nissan: Chronicles 2:29:17
10 Nissan: Joshua 4:19
12 Nissan: Ezra 8:31
13 Nissan: Esther 3:12
14 Nissan: Joshua 5:10, Ezra 6:19, Chronicles 2:35:1, 2:35:19
15 Nissan: [Numbers 33:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.33.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0)
16 Nissan: Chronicles 2:29:17
17 Nissan: [Genesis 8:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
?? Nissan: [Numbers 20:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.20.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0), Esther 3:7, Ezra 12:1, Chronicles 1:12:16, 2:29:3
1 Iyyar: [Numbers 1:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.1.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0)
14 Iyyar: 2:30:15
15 Iyyar: [Exodus 16:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.16.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0)
17 Iyyar: [Genesis 7:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.7.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
20 Iyyar: [Numbers 10:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.10.11?lang=bi&aliyot=0)
27 Iyyar: [Genesis 8:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
?? Iyyar: Kings 1:6:1, Ezra 3:8, Chronicles 2:3:2, 2:30:13
1 Sivan: [Ezekiel 31:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.31.1?lang=bi)
23 Sivan: Esther 8:9
?? Sivan: [Exodus 19:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.19.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0), Chronicles 2:15:10, 2:31:7
1 Tammuz: [Genesis 8:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
5 Tammuz: [Ezekiel 1:1-2](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.1.1-2?lang=bi)
9 Tammuz: Jeremiah 39:2, 52:5-6
1 Av: [Numbers 33:38](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.33.38?lang=bi&aliyot=0), Ezra 7:8-9
7 Av: Kings 2:25:8-9
10 Av: Jeremiah 52:12-13, [Ezekiel 20:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.20.1?lang=bi)
?? Av: Jeremiah 1:3, 28:1
1 Elul: Haggai 1:1
5 Elul: [Ezekiel 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.8.1?lang=bi)
24 Elul: Haggai 1:15
25 Elul: Ezra 16:15
1 Tishrei: [Genesis 8:13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Ezra 3:6, 18:2
10 Tishrei: [Ezekiel 40:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.40.1?lang=bi)
17 Tishrei: [Genesis 8:4](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
21 Tishrei: Haggai 2:1
23 Tishrei: Chronicles 2:7:10
24 Tishrei: Ezra 19:1
?? Tishrei: Kings 1:8:2, 2:25:25, Jeremiah 28:17, 41:1-2, Ezra 3:1, 17:72-18:2, Chronicles 2:5:3, 2:31:7
17 Marcheshvan: [Genesis 7:11](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.7.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
27 Marcheshvan: [Genesis 8:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)
?? Marcheshvan: Zecharia 1:1
4 Kislev: Zecharia 7:1
20 Kislev: Ezra 10:9
24 Kislev: Haggai 2:10
?? Kislev: Jeremiah 36:9, 36:22, Ezra 11:1
1 Tevet: [Genesis 8:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.8.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), Ezra 10:16
5 Tevet: [Ezekiel 33:21](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.33.21?lang=bi)
10 Tevet: Kings 2:25:1, Jeremiah 52:4, [Ezekiel 24:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.24.1?lang=bi)
12 Tevet: [Ezekiel 29:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.29.1?lang=bi)
?? Tevet: Jeremiah 39:1, Esther 2:16
1 Shevat: Deuteronomy 1:1
24 Shevat: Zecharia 1:7
1 Adar: [Ezekiel 32:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezekiel.32.1?lang=bi)
3 Adar: Ezra 6:15
13 Adar: Esther 9:1
14 Adar: Esther 9:17-18
15 Adar: Esther 9:18
25 Adar: Jeremiah 52:31
27 Adar: Kings 2:25:27

Comment: Happy Horseman Day